# To convert environment variable in batch file to power shell

Tags: powershell

I'm stuck in the below code snippet in conversion of batch to power shell :

batch file :

```
echo list vol > Test.txt

  for /f "tokens=2,3,4" %%i in ('diskpart /s Test.txt ^| findstr /r "Volume.[0-5]"') do (

            if "%%j"=="SYSTEM" set A_DRV=%%i
            if "%%k"=="SYSTEM" set B_DRV=%%i
            if "%%k"=="Test1" set C_DRV=%%i
            if "%%k"=="User" set D_DRV=%%i
            if "%%k"=="Test2" set E_DRV=%%i
```

It lists the disk volume,stores in Test.txt. Then a loop to assign drive letter name

I tried the below powershell snippet but I'm not able to set proper drive name .

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $4 ; $i++) 
{
     Get-Volume |Outfile "C:\Test.txt" -append -encoding UTF8
     $u = diskpart /s "C:\test.txt" |findstr /r `"Volume.[0-5]`" |Out-file "C:\Test.txt" -append -encoding UTF8
 if($i -eq 0)
 {
   Set-Volume -NewFileSystemLabel "A_DRV"
 }
 if($i -eq 1)
 {
   Set-Volume -NewFileSystemLabel "B_DRV"
 }
 if($i -eq 2)
 {
   Set-Volume -NewFileSystemLabel "C_DRV"
 }
 if($i -eq 3)
 {
   Set-Volume -NewFileSystemLabel "D_DRV"
 }
 if($i -eq 4)
 {
   Set-Volume -NewFileSystemLabel "E_DRV"
 }
           
}
```

Comment: What did you try yourself? Besides, it is probably easier and better to show the content of `Text.txt` and **explain** what you want to achieve. See also :[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems your batch file is assigning to variables, but your powershell script is overwriting the volume labels, can you explain what the batch file does?

Comment: @Bali C , for every $i in loop , Set-Volume should be used to set Drive letter name , which is not happening

Comment: "set Drive-Letter", what **exactly** does this mean?

Comment: There is no closing `)` in your batch file. Is this the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of the .bat file that sets environment variables to the volume numbers (###) based on the labels.  Although the first one uses the Ltr column.

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   BOOTCAMP     NTFS   Partition     37 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         EFI          FAT32  Partition    300 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2         PortableBas  NTFS   Partition   8189 MB  Healthy
```

```
'list vol' | diskpart | foreach {
  $split = -split $_ 
  if($split[2] -eq 'SYSTEM')   { $env:A_DRV = $split[1] }
  if($split[3] -eq 'SYSTEM')   { $env:B_DRV = $split[1] }
  if($split[3] -eq 'recovery') { $env:C_DRV = $split[1] }
  if($split[3] -eq 'C_DRV')    { $env:D_DRV = $split[1] }
  if($split[3] -eq 'O_DRV')    { $env:E_DRV = $split[1] }
}
```